# SQLite Select From Where x variable

Tags: python, sqlite, variables, select, where-clause

I'm learning SQLite (with python) and ran into a problem where i got lost.

I made a table:

```
dat.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS User_Login(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'User_Name' TEXT UNIQUE, 'Password' TEXT, 'Email' TEXT)")
    dat.execute("INSERT INTO User_Login('User_Name', 'Password', 'Email') VALUES('DM', 'pass', 'email@email.com')")
```

and now with a function i try to retrieve the password (pass) from User_Login with giving the Login_Name as variable

with data:

```
dat = data.cursor()
dat.execute("SELECT 'Password' FROM 'User_Login' WHERE 'User_Name'=?", [login])
pw = dat.fetchone()
print pw
```

But pw is always none, I tried alot of possible ways, but cant get it to work.
Checked the login with a print and that is stored right

Can someone please help me out or point me in the right direction?
I would be really thankful.

Greets

---

Indeed that needed to get changed, but it still doesn't work :(

```
with data:
dat = data.cursor()
dat.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'User_Login'")
dat.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'User_Login'(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'User_Name' TEXT UNIQUE, 'Password' TEXT, 'Email' TEXT)")
dat.execute("INSERT INTO User_Login('User_Name', 'Password', 'Email') VALUES('DM', 'Pass', 'email@email.com')")
```

and

```
with data:
    dat = data.cursor()
    dat.execute("SELECT 'Password' FROM 'User_Login' WHERE 'User_Name'=?", [login])
    pw = dat.fetchone()
    print pw
```

Still the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Try this SQL:

```
SELECT Password FROM User_Login WHERE User_Name=?
```

---

`field_name` and `'field_name'` are different.

Comment: Hello, Indeed that needed to get changed, but it still doesn't work :(

with data:
 dat = data.cursor()
 dat.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS 'User_Login'")
 dat.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'User_Login'(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 'User_Name' TEXT UNIQUE, 'Password' TEXT, 'Email' TEXT)")
 dat.execute("INSERT INTO User_Login('User_Name', 'Password', 'Email') VALUES('DM', 'Pass', 'email@email.com')")


and 

with data:
  dat = data.cursor()
  dat.execute("SELECT 'Password' FROM 'User_Login' WHERE 'User_Name'=?", [login])
  pw = dat.fetchone()
  print pw